What's wrong with my retention chart?
Recently, I had been assigned a problem to draw a retention chart from a given JSON data of user sessions over time. Here's the actual problem statement - "Draw a retention chart, which shows the month-on-month retention of users, based on whether they ran an inference on a particular month or not."
My initial two attempts were wrong, so later I switched to using mathematical formula rather than using logic and got the following graph :


Despite my best efforts, I'm still being told that my chart is wrong. I have cross-checked my chart with data and calculations and all seems good. I can't get my head around on what reasoning the chart above is flagged wrong. I'm not a DS expert, so I would really appreciate any help.
Here's the JSON data : https://drive.google.com/file/d/165tHQsT5K1Jvn5nqSq6PNQi8eeMHShg7/view
Here's the code I wrote : https://gist.github.com/2041011065-vishalkumar/4803b6addeda6db91a927c39f556f6e1
Here are the print statements :
Total users : 27662
Total dates : 182 | Beginning date : 2022-12-21
Total months : 7 | Beginning month : 2022-12
Months : ['2022-12', '2023-01', '2023-02', '2023-03', '2023-04', '2023-05', '2023-06']
Month : 2022-12 | CS : 79 | CE : 79 | CN : 0 | Active Users (Change) : 79 | Retention Rate : 100.0
Month : 2023-01 | CS : 79 | CE : 452 | CN : 428 | Active Users (Change) : 24 | Retention Rate : 30.38
Month : 2023-02 | CS : 452 | CE : 916 | CN : 847 | Active Users (Change) : 69 | Retention Rate : 15.27
Month : 2023-03 | CS : 916 | CE : 2379 | CN : 2286 | Active Users (Change) : 93 | Retention Rate : 10.15
Month : 2023-04 | CS : 2379 | CE : 6147 | CN : 6027 | Active Users (Change) : 120 | Retention Rate : 5.04
Month : 2023-05 | CS : 6147 | CE : 7962 | CN : 7792 | Active Users (Change) : 170 | Retention Rate : 2.77
Month : 2023-06 | CS : 7962 | CE : 10442 | CN : 10290 | Active Users (Change) : 152 | Retention Rate : 1.91

